# How to get routing parameters of simple single page app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a single page AngularJS application which is backed by Ruby on Rails server. The routing definition is only defined in RESTful Rails route.rb config, such as:

```
http://localhost/pages/:page_id/comments/:comment_id
```

The client is AngularJS with no routeProvider configuration. So it is just a simple AngularJS controller with view.

When I am in `http://localhost/pages/:page_id/comments/:comment_id.html`, I want to extract the value of `:page_id` and `:comment_id`. What is the best way to do it in AngularJS?

Note: I don't mind if really needed to use `routeProvider`. But I would only have one `templateUrl` in that case.

Comment: `$routeParams` maybe the best. but if you don't want to use `routeProvider`, you may use `$location` to parse by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$routeParams` service allows you to retrieve the current set of route parameters.

Requires the `ngRoute` module to be installed.

The route parameters are a combination of `$location`'s `search()` and `path()`. The `path` parameters are extracted when the `$route` path is matched.

Note that the `$routeParams` are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on `$routeParams` being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use `$route.current.params` to access the new route's parameters.

**Example:**

```
// Given:
 // URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
 // Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
 //
 // Then
 $routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

for [more infor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

**EDIT :**

If you are using `angular-ui-router`, you can inject `$stateParams`

check out this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

---

While routing is indeed a good solution for application-level URL parsing, you may want to use the more low-level `$location` service, as injected in your own service or controller:

```
var paramValue = $location.search().myParam;
```

This simple syntax will work for http://example.com/path?myParam=someValue. However, only if you configured the `$locationProvider` in the html5 mode before:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Otherwise have a look at the http://example.com/#!/path?myParam=someValue "Hashbang" syntax which is a bit more complicated, but have the benefit of working on old browsers (non-html5 compatible) as well.     [via : Javarome]

Comment: I came across that website also before. But the thing is that, my page is only single page without having ng-view or templateUrl at all

Comment: If You have ui-router then you can inject `$stateParams`

Comment: Can I have that without having to declare ng-view?

Comment: now check another solution of `$location` service added